# can't install python setup tools on linux

Tags: python, linux, django, centos

I issue the following command from my downloaded setup tools on centos:

```
python2.7 ez_setup.py install
```

I get the following error:

```
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-6.0.2.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmp8x3qjd
Now working in /tmp/tmp8x3qjd/setuptools-6.0.2
Installing Setuptools
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-23056.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

If use sudo like:

```
python2.7 ez_setup.py install
```

It says python2.7 command not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `sudo which python` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham use "python which": /usr/bin/python . If I use "which python2.7": /usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: did you put sudo before it?

Comment: yes I did, same results

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do something like `sudo $(which python2.7) ez_setup.py install`. `which` will locate the program in your *current* user's `${PATH}` variable.

Understanding as to why `python2.7` isn't in `root`'s path is something to investigate as well.

Comment: As root I have added python2.7 to my path with:  export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" but it still doesn't find python2.7

Comment: In your previous comment, you've stated that `python2.7` is located in `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`. Have you tried: `sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ez_setup.py install`?

Answer (score 0):

its a simple problem (may be!).
this may help !
type this as superuser :

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python - --user
```

this will download and install setuptools 6.0.2 : Python Package Index